# zend framework error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I started getting the following error today, but don't know why and what caused it.

[31-May-2010 03:52:10] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot run code from this file in conjunction with non encoded files in ZendFramework-1.10.5/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname/Com.php on line 547

I'm using zend framework version 1.10.5; although version 1.09 also has the same problem.

I only get this error in my production server, and cannot duplicate it from anywhere else.

Also note that I only get this error when I submit form with recaptcha.  If I remove recaptcha, it works fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up "Cannot run code from this file in conjunction with non encoded files" on Google gives you first result which suggests to turn off APC.

Look into the configuration of your webserver and turn off Alternative PHP Cache.
If you can't, contact your webmaster.

Second suggestion is that if you have your files encoded with Zend Encoder, make sure all the files are encoded including ZendFramework-1.10.5/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname/Com.php

Google is the friend!

Comment: Thank you!  Turning off APC seems to fix the error.  What I don't understand is why I just started to get this yesterday and there is nothing change.

Comment: Maybe the hosting provider turned it on yesterday. Consider accepting my answer if it helped solving your problem. Thank you